# MySQL Group By Clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I need to return the row with the maximum timestamp grouped by the `code` column but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm on MySQL 5.7.  I've run queries like this before and it seemed to work in the past. Not sure what's changed or what I could be doing wrong.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (code VARCHAR(20), timestamp DATETIME, id VARCHAR(20));

mysql> INSERT INTO test (code, timestamp, id) VALUES ('NA01M06152018','2018-06-15 21:01:00','111'),('NA01M06152018','2018-06-15 22:01:00','222'),('NA01M06152018','2018-06-15 23:01:00','333');

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+---------------+---------------------+------+
| code          | timestamp           | id   |
+---------------+---------------------+------+
| NA01M06152018 | 2018-06-15 21:01:00 | 111  |
| NA01M06152018 | 2018-06-15 22:01:00 | 222  |
| NA01M06152018 | 2018-06-15 23:01:00 | 333  |
+---------------+---------------------+------+

mysql> SELECT code, MAX(timestamp), id FROM test GROUP BY code;
+---------------+---------------------+------+
| code          | MAX(timestamp)      | id   |
+---------------+---------------------+------+
| NA01M06152018 | 2018-06-15 23:01:00 | 111  |
+---------------+---------------------+------+
```

I would expect the `id` to be `333` because that's the row with the max timestamp but I get `111` instead which is the row with the minimum timestamp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: If you were to run `SELECT code, MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp), id FROM test GROUP BY code;` which id would you expect it to return?

Comment: I added the tag `greatest-n-per-group`. This type of question has been answered many times on Stack Overflow. Follow the tag to find many solutions.